# How to keep a div's margin during sliding?

Tags: jquery, css, sliding

```
<button id="btnHome">HOME</button>
<div id="gall"></div>
```

CSS

```
#gall{
    margin-top:25px;
    height:70px;
    border:thin solid red;
}
```

JS

```
$("#btnHome").click(function() {
    $('#gall').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

[On this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bonaca/68myJ/18/) you can see that top margin of `#gall` during slidingDown is starting from `0` to `25px`, and vice versa during slidingUp.
I want `#gall` to keep it's margin of `25px` - just sliding keeping this margin value.

Comment: It's a bit of a naughty hack but putting `margin-top: 25px !important;` will fix it, stops the javascript over writing your CSS

Comment: yeah @Andy post it as answer!

Comment: @Andy how is it a naughty hack if it's 100% valid CSS?

Comment: @TimS. `!important` shouldn't ever be used really. It means any CSS affecting that margin elsewhere in the code will be completely ignored, it can solve problems in the future when you forget its there.

Comment: I'm against using `!important` too. But then again, it's native CSS. It just doesn't exactly fit in my book as "naughty hacks".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, give `!important` in your `margin-top` like this:

```
#gall{
  margin-top:25px !important;
  height:70px;
  border:thin solid red;
}
```

Second, jQuery `slideToggle()` can hide and show element with changing the height and who's know if jquery adding other css property and the solution is make your own animate like this:

```
$("#btnHome").click(function() {
    $('#gall').animate({height:'toggle'},"slow");
});
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, Michael, the second solution is more clearly - I believe. And it works more smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

This is part of the slideToggle feature, it animates the height AND the margin. As the margin is removed in javascript, we can overwrite it using !important so try

```
#gall{
    margin-top:25px !important;
    height:70px;
    border:thin solid red;
}
```